# Number of partitions of a number which don't include 1

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics, partitions

I'm looking for two things.

One is an asymptotic formula for the number of partitions (number of ways of writing an integer as a sum of smaller positive integers) with the condition that 2 is the smallest number permitted to appear in a partition.

Second is an asymptotic formula for the number of partitions of the above type that involve some fixed number of summands.

Comment: Just in case this proves useful: The respective counts of such partitions of n are OEIS A002865. This OEIS article gives definitions of several other partition-sets whose respective counts are this same sequence of integers.

Comment: @bof That was a typo! Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Note that the OEIS reference given by Rosie includes a claim from Vaclav Kotesovec that $$a(n) \approx \pi \frac{\exp(\sqrt{2n/3}\pi)}{12\sqrt{2} n^{3/2}} \left(1 - \frac{\frac{3\sqrt{\tfrac32}}{\pi} + \frac{13\pi}{24\sqrt{6}}}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{\frac{217\pi^2}{6912} + \frac{9}{2\pi^2} + \frac{13}8}{n}\right)$$

Comment: If $p(n)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$, then $p(n)-p(n-1)$
is the number of partitions of $n$ with no part equal to 1. Similarly,
if $p_k(n)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$ with $k$ parts,
then $p_k(n)-p_{k-1}(n-1)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$
parts with no part equal to 1. The proposed questions reduce to the
known asymptotics of $p(n)$ and $p_k(n)$. You'll need something like
$j+2$ terms in the asymptotic expansion of $p(n)$ to obtain $j$ terms
in that of $p(n)-p(n-1)$.

Comment: These partitions also involve a fairly new partition statistic, the mex (minimal excluded part).  Yours are the mex 1 partitions.  The articles I know on this topic, though, don't include asymptotics, but it sounds like the OEIS entry has what you need.